# Pyspark - read json files and return dataframe

Tags: json, pyspark

The JSON I am trying to read below using pyspark

```
test.json
{
  "Transactions": [
    {
      "ST": {
        "ST01": { "type": "271"},
        "ST02": {"type": "1001"},
        "ST03": {"type": "005010X279A1"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark - JSON read").master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "localhost") \
    .getOrCreate()

ST = StructType([
        StructField("ST01", StructType([StructField("type", StringType())])),
        StructField("ST02", StructType([StructField("type", StringType())])),
        StructField("ST03", StructType([StructField("type", StringType())])),
])
ST1 = StructType([
        StructField("ST01", StringType()),
        StructField("ST02", StringType()),
        StructField("ST03", StringType()),
])

Json_schema = StructType()
Json_schema.add("ST", ST1)
# Json_schema.add("ST", ST)
Schema = StructType([StructField("Transactions", ArrayType(Json_schema))])
df1 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("test.json", schema = Schema)
df1.select(F.explode("Transactions")).select("col.*").select("ST.*").show(truncate=False)
```

the output I wanted is like below the value of type has to be column value

```
+-----+------+------------+
|ST01 |ST02  |ST03        |
+-----+------+------------+
|271  |1001  |005010X279A1|
+------------+------------+
```

But using ST or ST1 schema

```
With ST --> each column is a struct field
+-----+------+--------------+
|ST01 |ST02  |ST03          |
+-----+------+--------------+
|[271]|[1001]|[005010X279A1]|
+-----+------+--------------+

With ST1 --> its a JSON value for ST01, ST02 and ST03 cols
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|ST01          |ST02           |ST03                   |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|{"type":"271"}|{"type":"1001"}|{"type":"005010X279A1"}|
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

I can do ST01.* and alias it, but the JSON I get as input is dynamic it may or may not contain all three tags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your JSON js dynamic and might not contain all three tags, one "dynamic" way to go is using a `for` loop with existing columns. Once having the column name, you can then [extract JSON object](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object) or [using expression](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr), like this

```py
df2 = df1.select(F.explode("Transactions")).select("col.*").select("ST.*")

# with ST schema (struct type)
for col in df2.columns:
  df2 = df2.withColumn(col, F.expr(f'{col}.type'))

# with ST1 schema (JSON string type)
for col in df2.columns:
  df2 = df2.withColumn(col, F.get_json_object(col, '$.type'))
```

Result:

```
+----+----+------------+
|ST01|ST02|ST03        |
+----+----+------------+
|271 |1001|005010X279A1|
+----+----+------------+
```